# Intersection of 3 circle not correct c++

Tags: c++, geometry

I am trying to find the common intersection(x,y) of 3 circles using c++. But i'm not getting the proper output. What am i doing wrong in my code? Here i my program i'm using to calculate the common intersection point. Here first i have calculated the intersection of two pixels which comes from quadric equation,as (x0,y0), (x1,y1). After that considering that 3rd circle intersects at atleast one point, i have used those two intersection points in 3rd circle, whichever satisfies the 3rd circle it is considered as the common intersection point of 3 circle. Am i doing anything wrong?

```
      vector<pix> obj; struct pix { int x; int y; };
      auto p0 = obj[stoi(r[2])][stoi(r[0])];
      auto p1 = obj[stoi(r[2])][stoi(r[1])];
      int ax = p1.x-p0.x; int ay = p1.y-p0.y;
      int bx = -ay; int by = ax;
      pix pv;
      pv.x = p1.x+bx; pv.y = p1.y+by;
      OrigImg.copyTo(cv_ptr->image);
      for(auto pi : obj[stoi(r[2])]) {
          float p0pi = sqrt(pow(p0.x-pi.x,2)+pow(p0.y-pi.y,2));
          float p1pi = sqrt(pow(p1.x-pi.x,2)+pow(p1.y-pi.y,2));
          float pvpi = sqrt(pow(pv.x-pi.x,2)+pow(pv.y-pi.y,2)); 
          float a1 = 2*(p1.x-p0.x);
          float b1 = 2*(p1.y-p0.y);
          float c1 = p0.x*p0.x-p1.x*p1.x+p0.y*p0.y-p1.y*p1.y-p0pi*p0pi+p1pi*p1pi;
          float a = a1*a1+b1*b1;
          float b = 2*(b1*c1 + b1*a1*p0.x - p0.y*a1*a1);
          float c = c1*c1+2*c1*p0.x*a1 + a1*a1*(p0.x*p0.x + p0.y*p0.y - p0pi*p0pi);
          int y0 = -(b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/2*a;
          int y1 = (b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/2*a;
          int x0 = -(b1*y0+c1)/a1;
          int x1 = -(b1*y1+c1)/a1;
          int x,y;
          cout<<"hello"<<x0<<"\t"<<y0<<"\t"<<x1<<"\t"<<y1<<endl;
          cout<<pow(x0-pv.x,2)+pow(y0-pv.y,2)<<"\t"<<pvpi*pvpi<<"\t"<<
                         pow(x1-pv.x,2)+pow(y1-pv.y,2)<<"\t"<<pvpi*pvpi<<endl;
          if(sqrt(pow(x0-pv.x,2)+pow(y0-pv.y,2))==pvpi) {
              x = x0; y = y0;
          }
          else if(sqrt(pow(x1-pv.x,2)+pow(y1-pv.y,2))==pvpi) {
              x = x1; y = y1;
          }
          if(x>=0 && x<OrigImg.rows && y>=0 && y<OrigImg.cols) {
              cv_ptr->image.at<cv::Vec3b>( y, x )[2] = 0;
              cv_ptr->image.at<cv::Vec3b>( y, x )[1] = 0;
              cv_ptr->image.at<cv::Vec3b>( y, x )[0] = 0;
          }
      }
  }
  image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
```

Here p0, p1, pv are the position of 3 circles which are at different position. Here what i'm trying to do it, i have saved the pixels belonging to one object in a map obj[obj_index][pixel_index] where pixel index is index for each unique pixel belonging to that pixel and obj_index is index for each unique object. 
After applying some pattern matching algorithm i get the r[0]=obj_index, r[1]=p0 index, r[2]=p1 index of object. Now what i'm trying to do it to visualize and check which pixels are present in current analysed object w.r.t previously saved object. 
Here the output comes like:

```
hello 150492    150336  -150180 -150336
4.51763e+10 873 4.52274e+10 873
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot run the code you show us. I do not know what values you are using, nor what the variables represent, nor what results you expect. (Also you seem to use "pixel" and "circle" interchangeably, but that may be an artifact of machine translation.)

Comment: Do you want to simply check if common point exists or do more complex calculations?

Comment: You forgot to initialise `x` and `y`, and neither of your conditions to assign values to them is true.